# Getting oxyplot mousedown tracker result

Tags: c#, oxyplot

I have a OxyPlot scatter plot in windows forms application (c#). By default, these kinds of plots, on mouse down display some kind of tooltip with values corresponding to the point. I cannot manage to find a way to "extract" the info of the maker, that is displayed in the tooltip on mosuedown event.

I have tried: Overwritting the tracker hit result class, converting point to client.

I am expecting: The content of the current/last mousedown tooltip to be stored in a variable, to be used in a event (ie show a messagebox with the value)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.